# Asp.Net 4 WebControl to Display Date & Time Picker

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I use aspnet 4 and c#.
My user need inserting DATE and TIME in a field.
The data to pass to DataBase has this format

```
2011-02-23 10:30:29.27 and DataType: datetime2
```

I can see in visual studio just a `Calendar` WebControl but it is able to handle just the date and not the time.

I found an interested WebControl at:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Specially functuion for Time Picker.

My question do you know any Free/Open source control?
If not any other solution WebControl or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are willing to use jQuery UI. If you are, Trent Richardson has extended the jQuery UI DatePicker to include a TimePicker.

This might work for you: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

There are a lot of sample on the page so it sould be pretty easy to use and you can wire up to your asp.net backend a number of ways including a static webmethod exposed via a scriptmanager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use jquery.. any ther ideas?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. You could extend the Asp.Net Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar (available here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ ) or just add a simple user control with dropdowns or textboxes. Also, I quick search produced this: http://www.markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=868292da-e93e-4e85-b455-41263ed15cd5 which may actually be what you are looking for. I have no experience with it but it's a free datetimepicker and could be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks DubMum for your info. Hopefully MS will add this controls in their ajaxcontroltoolkit one day :-)